# Change built-in colors

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just wanna ask how to change these build-in colors in Angular 2 material.

Its specified in the ng2-material docs:
`color: "primary"|"accent"|"warn"`

How to change colors in these palettes? Or even how to just change that blue color of the text?

I've tried this and it doesn't work.

```
md-input: {
  color: black;
  border-color: black
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this on the [Angular2 Material github](https://github.com/angular/material2) page

[Angular Material Home Page](https://material.angular.io/)

[image: Demo]

So assuming you are using `Angular-CLI`

[**Color Pallette**](https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-color-palette) - For selecting the colors you want to use and their shades, eg brown = $md-brown then choose a shade like 800.

**1**.) First Create a `./src/forest-theme.scss` file (Whatever name you want)

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';

@include md-core();

$forest-app-primary: md-palette($md-brown, 800);       // Brown  <-- CUSTOM COLOR HERE!
$forest-app-accent:  md-palette($md-green, A400);      // Green  <-- CUSTOM COLOR HERE!

$forest-app-warn:    md-palette($md-deep-orange, 500); // Orange <-- CUSTOM COLOR HERE!

$forest-app-theme: md-light-theme($forest-app-primary, $forest-app-accent, $forest-app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($forest-app-theme);
```

**2**.) Next: Add a new entry to the "styles" list in `angular-cli.json` pointing to the theme file (e.g., forest-theme.scss).

**angular-cli.json**

```
{
    "project": {
        "version": "blah",
        "name": "my_forest_app"
    },
    "apps": [ 
      {
        "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "forest-theme.scss"
        ]
      } 
    ],
}
```

**3**.) Then in your component you should be able to do something like this

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <md-toolbar color="primary">
      <span>Forest Application Title</span>
    </md-toolbar>
    <br/>
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button md-raised-button color="primary">Forest PRIMARY</button>
      <button md-raised-button color="accent">Forest ACCENT</button>
      <button md-raised-button color="warn">Forest WARN</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <md-input color="primary" placeholder="Primary Search"></md-input>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 Material'
  }

}
```

That should do it, any questions this page should answer them

## Update

[Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) has its own web site with plenty of [Guides](https://material.angular.io/guides)

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by @Logan H was right, but is outdated.

These are the new links for:

- [Theming your angular 2 material project
  **Github**.](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md)
- [Theming your angular 2 material project **Official documentation
  website**.](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

The steps are the same as @Logan H said in his answer:

1. Create a file (theme.scss) under the src/ folder of your angular 2 project
2. Add the file name in the array of styles specified in angular-cli.json or .angular-cli.json depends on your ng project version:

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
        "styles.less",
        "theme.default.scss"
]
```

**src/theme.scss**

```
//CHOOSE ONE, depending on your version, check UPDATE at the end
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';    
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the base styles for Angular Material core. We include this here 
// so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes 
// available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, 
// lighter, and darker
// hue.
$app-default: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-default-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$app-default-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$app-default-theme: mat-light-theme($app-default, $app-default-accent, $app-
default-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each 
// component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($app-default-theme);
```

In the comments is explained where to find the set of colors and options to choose. pallette.scss (\node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming_palette.scss)

**UPDATE**

In the last version of angular material 2 (Beta 3) some paths have changed, [see here.](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.3)

The breaking changes are:

1. New path to import pallette or to create your own theme. The path changes in **src/theme.scss** from ***@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';*** to ***@import '~@angular/material/theming';*** The same would happen if you are just importing a pre-built theme, the new path for amber theme is ***@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';***
2. Since Material 2 Beta 3 depends on Angular 4 (Angular latest version), we need to import in our main module the animation module from **BrowserAnimationsModule** or **NoopAnimationsModule** and I quote:

> Now that animations have been refactored into a separate package,
>   users of @angular/material need to explicitly import
>   BrowserAnimationsModule (or NoopAnimationsModule) from
>   @angular/package-browser/animations as well as installing
>   @angular/animations.